# Karnaugh map solution verification

Tags: boolean-algebra

> Find the minimal form of the logical expression in its DNF form as
> \begin{equation*}
>   d=x'y'z'+x'yz'+x'yz+xyz'
>  \end{equation*}

**My answer:**

[image]

After grouping $(1,3),(1,4)$ and $(1,4),(2,4)$ cells as doubles and $(1,1)$ cell as single, I obtain the minimal form as
\begin{equation*}
 d=x'y'z'+x'y+yz'
\end{equation*}
But the answer is $x'z'+x'y+yz'$.

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The Karnaugh map is a torus, so a rectangle containing $x'y'z'$ can be extended to the other side, becoming $x'z'$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this? I don't know torus.

Comment: Is my answer also correct?

Comment: So how do I know that further simplification is possible?

Comment: So can every single group be extended to the furthest corner in that row or column?

Comment: @ManjoyDas It is mere pattern recognition.

Comment: it's quite fishy